# Extract number from the date in pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

Does anyone know if it is possible to take the date from a random date in pl sql.

example.

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL
```

and here the output would be say :  26-10-2010 13:30:34

Now I want to have just the date as a number. In this case that would be 26.

Or is there some sort of function like IsNum that can recognize it for me. So I can just take 26 and leave the rest out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select to_char(sysdate,'DD') as day from dual
```

Comment: Thank you , I 've used yours since this one fits my needs perfectly.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use [`EXTRACT()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/extract.php), like so:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE) AS DAY FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD')
```

More you can read here: [LINK](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)

Answer (score 3):

All format models are described in the official [SQL Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924), take a look in case you need something else

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from 
     (select sysdate+rownum dates from  dual connect by rownum < (sysdate+15)-(sysdate))  
   where to_char(dates,'D') <> '1' and to_char(dates,'D') <> '7'
```